# mysql join virtual table

Tags: mysql, join

Ok so I have a ratings table. A new row is created for each user that leaves a rating. What I am atempting to do is create a query that will return the rating value for each specific row that exists now and 7 days ago.

The broad view is that I want to calculate the difference in the total average rating vs the total average rating of 7 days ago.

I have this which I think is the correct road to go down but I'm getting

```
Unknown column 'start_ratings.menu_item_id' in 'on clause'
```

---

```
SELECT *
FROM ratings end_ratings
JOIN (
SELECT menu_item_id as end_menu_item_id, AVG(value) AS end_rating
    FROM ratings
    WHERE  
        created_at > current_date - 7
        AND menu_item_id IS NOT NULL
        AND location_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY menu_item_id
) start_ratings ON (end_ratings.menu_item_id = start_ratings.menu_item_id)
WHERE menu_item_id IS NOT NULL
AND location_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have aliased the column `as end_menu_item_id`.  Just use that instead, as only the alias is known outside of the derived table's `()` in the `ON` clause, `SELECT` list, etc...

Because of this:

```
SELECT menu_item_id as end_menu_item_id, 
/*-----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```

Use this:

```
...) start_ratings ON (end_ratings.menu_item_id = start_ratings.end_menu_item_id)
/*----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
```